Computing Fubini-Study expectation values over $\mathbb{C}P^n$
In finite-dimensional textbook quantum mechanics, we postulate that states of our system are rays in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with dimension $\dim{\mathcal{H}} = n+1$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, inclusive of $n = 0$. We can instead say that states of our system are elements of the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P^n$. We can then define a notion of a uniform measure $d\Omega_n$ on $\mathbb{C}P^n$ called the Fubini-Study measure.
A particular problem of interest is computing the Fubini-Study expectation value of a function of pure states. In math, let $f: \mathbb{C}P^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and compute $\langle f\rangle_{d\Omega_n} \equiv \int d\Omega_n f.$
In chapter 7.6 of Geometry of Quantum States: An Introduction to Quantum Entanglement by Ingemar Bengtsson and Karol Życzkowski, the authors introduce local octant coordinates for $\mathbb{C}P^n$, which allows one to do explicit computations with $d\Omega_n$ in a straightforward (but tedious) manner.
What other local coordintizations exist for $\mathbb{C}P^n$ that are particularly good for doing computations involving $d\Omega_n$? Or, alternatively, is there a coordinate independent method amenable to do such computations?
